# Python extract JSON objects patterns between two timestamps

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to get total objects falls between certain dates and matched pattern objects from JSON array, below are few objects snippets -

Want to achieve -

After giving input (Number of days) the script should display the count of objects that will match below conditions.

- Objects created before a number of days provided. [WORKING]
- Objects that only match the pattern.  [PARTIALLY WORKING]

  ```
  jsonstring=''' [{
       "creationTimestamp": "2018-06-13T00:10:56.515-07:00",
       "guestOsFeatures": [
         {
           "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
         }
       ],
       "id": "6574596365405224336",
       "labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
       "name": "cc-r-2018-06-13-06-56-24-31"         
     },
     {
       "archiveSizeBytes": "1411180288",
       "creationTimestamp": "2018-06-02T02:47:27.226-07:00",
       "guestOsFeatures": [
         {
           "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
         }
       ],
       "id": "4581941886084536001",
       "labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
       "name": "cc-r-2018-06-13-09-32-16-32"
     }]'''
  ```

For that, I am calculating the timedelta then getting all objects fall under that time but unable to get only matched data based on input pattern below is my code

```
    import json, datetime

def get_matched_objects(data,before,pattern=None):
    sorted_data = sorted(data,key=lambda x:datetime.datetime.strptime(x['creationTimestamp'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z'),reverse=True)
    recent_date=sorted_data[0]['creationTimestamp']
    delta_days=datetime.datetime.strptime(recent_date,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z') - datetime.timedelta(days=before)
    object_list=[]
    matched_list=[]
    print("finding objects between {0} and {1}".format(recent_date,delta_days))
    for p in sorted_data:
        found_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(p['creationTimestamp'],'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
        if  found_date > delta_days:
            object_list.append(p)
        for key, val in p.items():
            if val == pattern:
                matched_list.append(p)
                       
    print("Objects created before {0} days: {1}".format(before,len(object_list)))
    print("Objects matched with given pattern: {0}".format(len(matched_list)))
    
    
data = json.loads(jsonstring)
result=get_matched_objects(data,2,'cc-r-2018-06-13-06-56-24-31')
```

And below is the output-

```
finding objects between 2018-06-13T00:10:56.515-07:00 and 2018-06-11 00:10:56.515000-07:00
Objects created before 2 days: 1
Objects matched with given pattern: 1
```

But I want to include below pattern as well

```
"guestOsFeatures": [
      {
        "type": "VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE"
      }
    ],
```

if I try to find `VIRTIO_SCSI_MULTIQUEUE` I get 0 matched, any lead to include nested objects as well?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain more about what you are trying to do.  Your code appears to find all of the objects that were created no more than 10 days before the most recently created object in the list.  You wrote that you also wanted "objects that only match the pattern" but didn't say what the pattern was, and your code doesn't appear to try to check objects for patterns.  If you described the pattern, and showed the code that you wrote that tried to match the pattern, and described what was wrong with the results that your code generated, then we would have more to work with.

Comment: @Andrew Merril: I just added more details to explain the problem I am facing and need help to achieve.

Comment: Regex is the wrong tool. Parse first with the `json` module. Then use other tools to iterate through the data.

Comment: You'll get better help on StackOverflow if you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Your current example is not runnable (has errors); it's not minimal (most fields in the data structure are not used, so delete them in your example); and it requires us to put them in a separate JSON file (get rid of that dependency and just define the minimal data structure in code). The example code should produce the wrong answer, and you should explain what you want instead. Invest effort in your question and you'll get better help.

Comment: @FMc Thanks for the advice, I followed and put the correct reproducible issue, where I want to include a pattern from nested JSON object as well, hope this explains a bit more.

Comment: @jpmc26 I just removed the regex keyword and looking for JSON solution only